# How to get Json data in ajax after a mysql query

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

For my bookshop, I started to built a cashdesk script. This is a very simple form, with an ajax dynamic search. This is a script for a local PC, so the script will not be publish on the web.

When I scan the EAN code, I've my form fill with title, author, editor and price. The book is ready to add in the basket.

Now I'm trying to introduce Json in this script : but I don't understand how to get the values of the mysql query in the script, and put them in the correct fields of my cashdesk form.

I've tested the Mysql query and the Json.

The query

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');

include('connexion.php');
$connect_db = connect();

$i = 0;
$tmp = array();


$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT jos_vm_product.product_id,product_name,product_author,product_editor,jos_vm_product_price.product_price FROM jos_vm_product INNER JOIN jos_vm_product_price ON (jos_vm_product.product_id = jos_vm_product_price.product_id) WHERE product_EAN = '$_POST[EAN]'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$tmp[$i] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($tmp);

close();
?>
```

A json exemple :

```
[{"product_id":"7097","product_name":"Paix pour tous - Livre audio","product_author":"Wayne W. Dyer","product_editor":"Ada","product_price":"20.28"}]
```

The ajax script

```
var xhr = null;
  function getXhr()
  {
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else if(window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  try
  {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
  catch (e)
  {
  xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
}
else
{
alert("Not Working");
xhr = false;
}
}

function ajaxEAN()
{
getXhr();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
{

var data = '{"product_id": "product_id", "product_name":"product_name", "product_author":"product_author", "product_editor":"product_editor", "product_price":"product_price"}';

oData = JSON.parse( data);
for( var i in oData){
document.getElementById( i).value = oData[i];
}

}
}
xhr.open("POST",'ajaxrecupaddr.php',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
EAN = document.getElementById("EAN").value;
xhr.send("EAN="+EAN);
}
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Wow! That is one hell of an unsafe PHP script.

Comment: Are you saying that you simply can't take JSON from response and use it in your JS?

Comment: please reframe your question.. add what u did .. what u got out of it ... what was expected.

Comment: This script is not for the web... It's for my real life shop. Yes, I don't understand how I can use my json in the Js

Answer (score 0):

As far as  understand, you simply can't take a JSON from response. If so, than you simply should do:

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
   if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {        
     oData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     for(var i = 0; i < oData.length; i++) {
         for( var key in oData[i]){
            document.getElementById(key).value = oData[i][key];
         }    
     }
}
```

There, `xhr.responseText` will return a string with JSON received from server.

Also, few notes:
Instead of

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
```

you should better use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json;');
```

Also, in line below you are opened to SQL Injections:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT jos_vm_product.product_id,product_name,product_author,product_editor,jos_vm_product_price.product_price FROM jos_vm_product INNER JOIN jos_vm_product_price ON (jos_vm_product.product_id = jos_vm_product_price.product_id) WHERE product_EAN = '$_POST[EAN]'");
```

instead of simply doing `WHERE product_EAN = '$_POST[EAN]'` you should do, at least, `WHERE product_EAN = '".mysql_real_esape_string($_POST["EAN"]) . "'`:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("SELECT jos_vm_product.product_id,product_name,product_author,product_editor,jos_vm_product_price.product_price FROM jos_vm_product INNER JOIN jos_vm_product_price ON (jos_vm_product.product_id = jos_vm_product_price.product_id) WHERE product_EAN = '".mysql_real_esape_string($_POST["EAN"]) . "'");
```

See more about [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). It will correctly escape all potentially dangerous symbols and will save you from errors when you have `'` symbol in EAN. Also, read warning shown on a page linked above. You should better change your database extension as MySQL extension is deprecated.

Comment: I've made some corrections to my post. I've added an exemple for the Json that I tried to used in the javascript. FAngel, your solution doesn't work, and I don't understand why.

Comment: Learn how to use developer tools or firebug (depends on your browser). It will help you with finding a problem. Also, take a look at updated answer. For loop is changed. Your PHP returns an array of objects. And you are trying to work with it like with a simple object

Comment: I've found this solution and that's works : I've found this solution and that's works : 

    oData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    for( var i in oData){
    document.getElementById("product_id").value = oData[0].product_id;
    document.getElementById("product_name").value =  oData[0].product_name;
    document.getElementById("product_author").value =  oData[0].product_author;
    document.getElementById("product_editor").value =  oData[0].product_editor;
    document.getElementById("product_price").value =  oData[0].product_price;
    }

Thanks.

Comment: Hm. Have you tried my updated code? It should work too. And it is not so wordy)